# Calculate $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos(wx)}{x^2}dx$ using complex analysis technique

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

In a complex analysis test an exercise asks to calculate ($w \in \Bbb{R}$): $$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos(wx)}{x^2}dx$$
Of course I need to solve it with complex analysis technique. I have used all the tricks I know such as integrate on a semi-circumference of radius $R$ in $\Bbb{C}$ and then let $R \to \infty$ but everything I have tried to do just seemed useless. Thank you for every hint or solution to this problem!

Comment: Hint: this function is holomorfic ( in particular it is defined in x=0 ).

Comment: @JakubAndruszkiewicz I know, in $x=0$ there is a removable singularity but still I can't proceed, do you have any other hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to use complex methods in this, the place I'd do it is in proving$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}dx=\pi$$(e.g. by the residue theorem; see [here](https://19040886-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/peeterjoot2/math2011/sincIntegral.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cr4EBMt1hgWHGLPTPwD_g0Wezo_-eR7_nv8aafrWy1ratvvIMrZlbQhWjkPSLQAS0F8f9Qhd1wGVB7usIyupT6O8Ze2Ik_VXJyxWuj2dXzrrI0WzYYympQ9bbI4h6Ag0ta1G4eEc8qT1CmwxLJ5q_XbCwcacGWtvHMKfCQnWFIOKHHm1Y-_IxjsdPIMn8q0xVYM1fJ6mQN5MV8KniFLMVGZcMnVUL1s6m4UpsOdWX-rBeGXZa4%3D&attredirects=0) for the gory details) so$$\left|k\right|\pi=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin^{2}kx}{x^{2}}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1-\cos2kx}{2x^{2}}dx.$$Hence$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin^{2}x\cos wx}{x^{2}}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{2\cos wx-\cos\left(w-2\right)x-\cos\left(w+2\right)x}{4x^{2}}dx\\=\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\left|w-2\right|+\left|w+2\right|-2\left|w\right|\right).$$As a sanity check, the case $w=0$ needs to give $\pi$, and lo and behold it does.

Comment: What have you done in this equality? $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin^{2}x\cos wx}{x^{2}}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{2\cos wx-\cos\left(w-2\right)x-\cos\left(w+2\right)x}{4x^{2}}dx$

Comment: @edo1998 $\sin^2x=(1-\cos 2x)/2$ followed by the product-of-two-cosines-as-sum-of-two-cosines formula.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail how did the absolute values appear in the answer.

Comment: @user While the cases $k=0,\,k>0$ are separately trivial, the obvious substitution $y=kx$ induces a sign change if $k<0$ due to exchanging the $\pm\infty$ limits. Another way to see it is the integrand is even in $k$.

Comment: I know that the absolute value is the correct result. From the attached drawing it is however not clear how to obtain it from the residue theorem.  :)

Comment: @user It"s probably easiest to just use the residue theorem for $k=1$, then do the rest by substitution. In fact, in hindsight my preferred derivation from comes methods is a Schwinger parametrisation instead.

Comment: Of course, but the residue theorem is certainly valid for any (real) value of $k$.  I think the main shortcoming of the attached drawing is that it considers from the beginning the $\sin|k|x$ integral. Otherwise it would become immediately clear that the integration contours  for positive and negative $k$ should be different ($C_1$ and $C_2$ according to the drawing)... This however has nothing to do with the beutiful idea to reduce the problem to $\sin^2 kx/x^2$ case. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not a complex analytic method, but Fourier inversion formula also can give you the result. It holds that
$$
\int_{-1}^1 e^{-i\xi x}dx=\frac{2\sin \xi}{\xi}.
$$ Let $f(x) = 1_{[-1,1]}(x)$. This shows $\widehat{f}(\xi)=\frac{2\sin \xi}{\xi}$ and therefore, $\widehat{(f*f)}(\xi)=f(\xi)^2=4\frac{2\sin^2 \xi}{\xi^2}$. 
The given integral is
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos(wx)}{x^2}dx&=&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)e^{iwx}}{x^2}dx\\
&=&2\pi \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left[\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}\right](w)\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{2}(f*f)(w).
\end{eqnarray}$$ Finally, we have
$$\begin{eqnarray}
(f*f)(w)&=&\int f(w-y)f(y)dy\\
&=&\int_{|w-y|<1,|y|<1}dy\\
&=&\begin{cases}2-w,\quad w\in[0,2)\\2+w,\quad w\in(-2,0]\\0,\quad|w|>2\end{cases}\\
&=&(2-|w|)1_{|w|<2}.
\end{eqnarray}$$ This gives that the given integral is equal to
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}(2-|w|)1_{|w|<2}.
$$

Comment: I'll look at your answer when I'll have the knowledge to understand it!

Comment: @edo1998 I hope it will help you soon! :)

Answer (score 0):

$$I(w)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos(wx)}{x^2}dx$$
$$I'(w)=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)\sin(wx)}{x}$$
$$I''(w)=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin^2(x)\cos(wx)dx$$
$$I''(w)=-\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin^2(x)e^{iwx}dx$$
and then try integration by parts. Alternatively:
$$I(w)=\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)e^{iwx}}{x^2}dx$$
$$I(w)=\Re\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin^2(x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(iw)^nx^{n-2}}{n!}dx$$