# Characteristic functions to evaluate integral

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

How do you work out $\int e^{itx} \sin^2(t) / t^2 dt$?

Given the integral is with respect to $t$, I'm thinking this is about [the inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formula), but the exponent would have to be $-itx$. (In that case, the result would be the density for the [sum of two independent uniformly distributed random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4313475/348586) on $[-1, 1]$.)

The other thing is that, if you swap $x$ and $t$, the integral might be a characteristic function, but I don't think $\sin^2(x) / x^2$ can be a density (it integrates to greater than 1).

Comment: If you mean the *definite* integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{itx} \sin^2(t) / t^2 dt$, the following posts can help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253230/a-fourier-transform-using-contour-integral?noredirect=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079815/calculate-int-limits-infty-infty-frac-sin2x-coswxx2dx-using?noredirect=1.

Comment: $\int e^{itx} \sin^2(t) / t^2 dt$ is same as $\int e^{-itx} \sin^2(t) / t^2 dt$ since the imaginary part is $0$.

Comment: @Gonçalo: the OP ask for a method based on Fourier transform. Your link does not offer clear answers.

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sinc%28t%29%5E2+*+exp%28iwt%29+dt) the inetgral has a solution. 

If you now how to solve this equation with $exp(-itx)$ and say the answer is $I(t)$ then integrating with the $exp(+itx)$ kernel will result in the answer $I^{\ast}(t)$, i.e., the complex conjugated output

Comment: @Mittens, those answers may not be clear for you, but are clear for others. Let the OP decide whether they are useful or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fourier transform of the law of the symmetric uniform distribution on $[-1,1]$ is given by
$$\frac12\int^1_{-1}e^{-itx}\,dx=\frac{\sin t}{t}$$

The Fourier transform of the distribution of the sum of two i.i.d symmetric uniform random variables $X_1,X_2$ on $[-1,1]$ is (I leave details to the OP)
$$\phi_{X_1+X_2}(t)=E[e^{it(X_1+X_2)}]=\frac{\sin^2}{t^2}$$

Since $\phi_{X_1+X_2}\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ (I leave details to the OP), the inversion formula states that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-itx}\frac{\sin^2}{t^2}\,dt=f(x)$$
where $f$ is the density of the law of $X_1+X_2$, that is (I leave details to the OP)
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac14\big(\mathbb{1}_{(-1,1)}*\mathbb{1}_{(-1,1)}\big)(x)=\frac{1}{4}\int^1_{-1}\mathbb{1}_{(-1,1)}(x-y)\,dy\\
&=\frac14(2-|x|)_+
\end{align}

Comment: For $t \leq 0$, $F_{X_1 + X_2}(t) = \frac{1}{8}t^2 + \frac{1}{2}t + \frac{1}{2}$. For $t \in (0, 2]$, $F_{X_1 + X_2}(t) = \frac{-1}{8}t^2 + \frac{1}{2}t + \frac{1}{2}$. For $t > 2$, $F_{X_1 + X_2}(t) = 1$. So for $x \leq 0$, $f(x) = \frac{1}{4}x + \frac{1}{2}$. For $x \in (0, 2]$, $f(x) = \frac{-1}{4}x + \frac{1}{2}$. For $x > 2$, $f(x) = 0$. I think this is a less advanced way of working out $f$ (I couldn't follow indicators and the $+$ subscript).

Comment: @johnsmith: $x_+=\max(x,0)$; in a similar way, $x_-=-\min(0,x)=\max(0,-x)$. The function $t\mapsto\mathbb{1}_{A}(t)$ has value $1$ if $t\in A$ and $0$ otherwise. Recall that if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables whose distributions have densities $f$ and $g$ respectively, then the distribution of $X+Y$ also has density $h$ and it given by the convolution of the densities $f$, and $g$, i.e. $h(x)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x-y) g(y)\,dy$.